# How to pass data into form and response onkeyup or keydown using json, ajax

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

How to fetch data and pass. into form and response customername onkeyup or keydown json and php.

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", 'root', "", "laravel");
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from customers");

while ($result2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  $data[] = $result2['customername'];
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Here is HTML code with javascript ajax:-

```
        <div id="demo">
     CustomerName: <input type="search" name="customername">
      </div>
         <script>
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = "connection.php";
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
            xmlhttp.send();

            function myFunction(response) {
                var arr = JSON.parse(response);

                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr;
            }
        </script>
```

How pass into form and response on keyup or keydown and related suggestions customername should display down. I am new to JSON and javascript and examples sites. Thanks in advance. All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: `<?` and `?>`? Where are they?

Comment: Ajax works well for json and use json_encode($data) in php to return json formatted data.

Comment: Also remove var out = $result2; and make a loop over arr to display in table format.

Comment: Thanks your suggestions. All suggestions are working. But i want pass this data into form response using keyup or keydown and that related customername. waiting for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code sample

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", 'root', "", "laravel");
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from customers");
$dataForJSON = array()
while($result2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $dataForJSON[] = $result2['customerName'];
}
echo json_encode($dataForJSON);
```

Use this code to return data from json and this will work fine with `JSON.parse(response)`

Comment: Thanks your suggestions. All suggestion are working. But i want pass this data into form response using keyup or keydown and that related customername. waiting for your answers.

Comment: what you want to pass into form? do you want to reflect input field with name of customer when ajax returns name or something else?